# How I can share parts of my source code for use inside of other projects? (like a library)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I'm starting to use VisualSVN Server ( http://www.visualsvn.com/downloads )

I have a project in a directory like this:

```
MyAPP_PHP
    - directory General 1 tool for conection db
    - directory General 2 tool for manage strings
    - directory General 3 ... etc.
    - directoryCLASS for this app
    - index.php
    - [other files]
```

I'm using subversion with tortoise for store a copy of all code inside of repositorie.
And also I want to have 3 different repositories within this project.
But using tortoise I can not specify a different path to these directories. 
I'm not allowed to define new repositories. 
How I can do this?

For your time thanks...

Comment: I want to ask if I can make 3 sub repositories, for use in other projects, not only one

Comment: or let my tray to rewrite question rigth now and when I finiched, give me your opinion

Comment: I did it, What do you think?

Comment: It's more clean English now, but really, really "unclear what you're asking". BTW: when it will be "clear" - it will be "offtopic"

Comment: I change title... If I write someting wrong please tell me... I want to know.

Comment: And I want to sugest you a new idea, I think will be usefull if this page give to user some kind of three to select a topic and organice question on one, two or more topics. And this would allow people we could find information regarding a specific topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read about SVN-externals in SVN Book and understand topic

   - In your current tree you'll have to covert into 3 separate externals three dirs (`Class General 1`, `Class General 2`,`Class General 3`), which you'll add into all subsequent projects
   - In you'll refactor tree and collect `Class General**` under common directory (smth. like `/Core/Class General**`) you can to have and add only one externals
2. You can checkout and inspect this [Externals Proving Ground Repository](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/subversion-troubleshoot-b/) (maybe just trunk will be OK) in order to see, how linking of one directory in repository to real directory in another repository was implemented (`/trunk/lib` in `subversion-troubleshoot-b` repo is really `/trunk/lib` in `subversion-troubleshoot` repository)

<sub>Escribe en español, será más comprensible (para los lectores) que su Inglés</sub>

Comment: puedo preguntar en español? esta es una pagina de ingles solamente no?

Comment: I rearrange my question, What do you think?

Comment: @rubenrp81 - Sí, se puede: al menos se puede intentar tener ilegible, pero bueno, español en lugar de malo y no comprensible Inglés. I think, you still have to rewrite question in more short and easy phrases - nodody can grok, what you want to get *really*

Comment: I think your answer is correct, I found that issue of Externals in the book and other related too, that's the answer, thanks